# Google Sheets SUMIFS - apply REGEXTRACT to sum_range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have the following Google Sheets table and want to calculate the total sums of various medications prescribed:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Type | Amount (in g) | Daily dosage (in g) |
| 2 | A | 60 | 2 |
| 3 | B | 25 mg/capsule | 30 pieces, 0-0-1 for 30 days |
| 4 | A | 10 | 0.5 |

This is very easy for medication type A, as I can just look in column B.

My issue is that the entries associated with **medication type B** don't only consist of digits, so I need to apply two REGEXTRACTs.

```
"[0-9]{2}"

"(\d+) pieces"
```

That is all fine and would work.

**But how do I get around the issue that the sum_range in SUMIFS needs to be digits?**

Because something like this would not work afaik:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS(REGEXEXTRACT(C2,"(\d+) pieces")...
```

I cannot change the way this data is entered and also don't want to create additional columns if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use `VALUE`.

From [Google Sheets List Function](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)

| Type | Name | Syntax | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Text | VALUE | VALUE(text) | Converts a string in any of the date, time or number formats that Google Sheets understands into a number. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220?hl=en) |